# AngularJS : Controller is not getting updated factory value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I'm updating an object property in a factory and it doesn't seem to be updating the property referenced in the controller.

**Say I have a factory that looks something like this...**

```
app.factory('User', function ($http)
{  
 $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    var User = {
        Name: "",
        JobTitle: "",
        isloaded: false
    };

User.GetUser = function (ID)
{
       $http(
            {
                url: "webservice uri",
                method: "GET"
            }
        ).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {               
            User.isloaded= true;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {

        })      
}
return User;
});
```

the property 'isloaded' is initially set to false, and then once the $http calls goes through the success callback, it is eventually set to false.

**And then I have a controller that looks something like**

```
controllers.DefaultCtrl = function($scope, User)
{ 
    $scope.showMessage = User.isloaded;
    $scope.getUser = function ()
    {
        User.GetUser("11111");
    }
    $scope.getUser();   
    }
```

**which is associated with this html**

```
<h1>{{showMessage.isloaded ? 'success' : 'Loading...'}}</h1>
```

Ultimately I would like it to say 'success', however, the text never changes in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning a primitive:

```
 $scope.showMessage = User.isloaded;
```

`showMessage` is assigned to false, it is not "pointing" to the `isloaded` property.

What you should probably do is set the `User` to be a scope variable, something like:

```
controllers.DefaultCtrl = function($scope, User)
{ 
  $scope.user = User;
  $scope.user.getUser("11111");   
}
```

and then in your html you can do:

```
<h1>{{user.isloaded ? 'success' : 'Loading...'}}</h1>
```